# VBA error 1004 when trying to sort data based on multiple keys

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort my data based on 3 keys but the 3rd key must have a custom list to sort on. I am getting a 1004 error on my sort when I try to run it.

```
With Worksheets(srcSheet).Range("A3:" & CC2 & XY)
  .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range("D3:D" & XY), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Key2:=.Range("C3:C" & XY), Order2:=xlAscending, _
              Key3:=.Range("E3:E" & XY), Order3:=xlAscending, _
              CustomOrder:="Team1, Team5, Leader, Team3, Team10", _
              Header:=xlNo
End With
```

I'm not sure where I have went wrong, I have looked at other suggestions online and even recorded a macro but as you are aware the macro code is incredibly long winded and I would like it to be as efficient as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Correct code added below thanks to Ashleedawg:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
 .SortFields.Clear
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D" & XY), Order:=xlAscending
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C" & XY), Order:=xlAscending
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E" & XY), Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="Team1, Team5, Leader, Team3, Team10"
 .SetRange Range("A3:" & CC2 & XY)
 .Header = xlNo
 .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Do the sort conditions one by one first and check if any are flagged as invalid.

Comment: I'd suggest removing all but one sort key, get that working, and then add in the other one at a time, testing between.  See also Chip Pearson's [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) for more troubleshooting methods.

Comment: And is Worksheets(srcSheet).Range("A3:" & CC2 & XY)  the address you expect?

Comment: Variable `srcSheet` set? `Worksheets(srcSheet)` exists? You intend to sort the sheet from active workbook?

Comment: Actually - your `With` is referring to a range of cells, and then each key has a `.` which is referring to "cells within cells".  For example: **Key1** is referring to: `Worksheets(srcSheet).Range("A3:" & CC2 & XY).Range("D3:D" & XY)` which obviously doesn't make sense.

Comment: AFAIK there is no `CustomOrder` parameter in [Range.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method?

Comment: Maybe you messed up with [CustomOrder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfield.customorder)?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, @ashleedawg you were correct, i was referring to ranges multiple times which i don't think helped. I have amended my question to show the correct code in case someone runs into this in the future. If you could create it as an answer then i'll mark it as the answer. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
 .SortFields.Clear
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D" & XY), Order:=xlAscending
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C" & XY), Order:=xlAscending
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E" & XY), Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="Team1, Team5, Leader, Team3, Team10"
 .SetRange Range("A3:" & CC2 & XY)
 .Header = xlNo
 .Apply
End With
```